# Web Deploy package throws ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST when deployed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, microsoft-web-deploy

After creating a WDP from an aspnet solution, the `[project name].deploy.cmd` file returns this error when executed:

`Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
More Information: Site 'freedomstoreusa.azurewebsites.net' does not exist.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST.
Error count: 1.`

My objective is to deploy the package to this site as if it were publishing to azure from visual studio 2017. What is causing this issue, what can resolve it and what are some alternatives to packaging and deploying a website?

Here are my settings in the package wizard:
[image]

Comment: Please try to specify ``Site name`` with {app name} **freedomstoreusa** instead of freedomstoreusa.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry my friend, same problem `Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
More Information: Site '{app name} freedomstoreusa.azurewebsites.net' does not exist.`

Comment: I believe it is searching for an IIS site on the current computer with the matching name; not a website. There is some extra step I am missing in order to deploy to azure using this a WDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what can resolve it and what are some alternatives to packaging and deploying a website?

I build and package the web application project, and [use MSDeploy.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages#using-msdeployexe) to deploy the web application, which works fine on my side.

*Command:*

[image]

*TestSite.SetParameters.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="{app name}" />
</parameters>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing some similar troubles, could you provide me the command template  you used?

Comment: I too experience similar trouble even with msdeploy.exe

Answer (score 1):

I came here with the same problem but the image in the question and the answer from Fei Han solve my problem I was creating a File System Package not a Web Deploy Package which will create App.SetParameters.xml and the App.zip in the selected folder it also will ask for the app name an then you can use that auto generated file for the param -setParamFile: